# Express + node.js API filtering

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, rest, express

I am developing a node API.
I have endpoint like `GET /messages`

This wll return all messages. I want to have pagination on this endpoint something like

```
GET /messages?filter=my_filter_string&limit=10&offset=10
```

The filter statement will be like this

```
{fieldName1}={fieldValue1}&...{fieldNameN}>{fieldValueN}.
Operations can be =, > or <. < and > operations are only for number, integers and dates
```

I using sequelize as the ORM and postgresql as DB.
My question is how can I parse the my_filter_statement and convert it into a search criteria object for sequelize.
Also if I call the API like

```
GET /messages?filter="id=10&contentlength>20"&limit=10&offset=10
```

It is not working

Comment: I was wondering a similar thing.. or maybe just use ?filter={where:{id:10}} but I have no idea if this is secure at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have, for example:

```
GET /messages?greater=1&less=5&limit=10&offset=10
```

And then in node:

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```

And match the query parameters, such as greater/less than (which could be shortened to "gt" and "lt"), to the symbols you need in your statement?

Comment: I can't have like `GET /messages?greater=1&less=5&limit=10&offset=10`
It is very specific requirement. I have to develop as I mentioned in my question

Comment: In that case, I'm sure you would be able to use encodeURI and decodeURI?

Comment: Can you give a specific use case
I mean how can I call the API. I mean do I have to encode `my_filter_statement`.
How can I parse it on server side. Can you modify your answer to include that case or can you point me to any example or documentation.